# How to remove ?p= from wordpress short links

Tags: php, functions, shortlink

How to remove ?p= from WordPress short links?

I removed ?p= from wp_get_shortlink and it's get the links without ?p= successfully but the problem that this links not working until added ?p= so how can make links working without added ?p=.

Comment: The question as it is right now do not make much sense. Those are the wordpress short links, if you are not happy with them, make your own....

Comment: do you want to display url like e.g. : site-url.com/post instead of site-url.com/?p=22   ??

Comment: @PunitPatel To appear like this: site-url.com/22 (without ?p=)

Comment: @Yogu It's very simple just add %post_id% in setting > permalink > in post name. [![Please check image for solution][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3ovY.png

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you removed `?p=` from the link but you can use `get_shortlink` filter to override the shortlink. You can refer following article for more details.

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-display-wordpress-shortlinks-in-your-theme/

Reference to `get_shortlink` filter: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_shortlink/

Can you share some more details on how you removed the ?p= from the link?

Comment: I replace $shortlink = home_url( '?p=' . $post_id ); to $shortlink = home_url( '' . $post_id ); from wp_get_shortlink and i used it like this wp_get_shortlink(post_id), and it's wokring the issue when go to the link it's give me 404 not found.

Answer (score 1):

@yogu You can add [image: %post_id%] in permalink to get required structure. `site-url.com/22 (without ?p=)`

For specific post you can add following function and add specific condition for it :

```
add_filter( 'post_link', 'custom_permalink', 10, 3 );
function custom_permalink( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {
    // For shortlink condition
    if (  'Shortlink Condition here' ) {
        $permalink = trailingslashit( home_url('/'. $post->ID .'/' ) );
    }
    return $permalink;
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'custom_rewrite_rules');
function custom_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
    // This rule will will match the post id in %post_id% struture
    $new_rules['^([^/]*)-([0-9]+)/?'] = 'index.php?p=$matches[2]';
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
    return $wp_rewrite;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for this but sure I know that but what I need to do to remove ?p= for the short links only not the all posts links.

Comment: I have updated answer as per your need. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress redirects without the parameter: ?p. Regardless of whether it's pages or posts ...

For example:
site.com/922 (post or page ID...), this should redirect.

If you want to change link one at the head of your site:

```
add_filter('pre_get_shortlink', function () {
    return home_url('/') . get_the_ID();
}, 10, 3);
```

In wordpress docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_shortlink/

Answer (score 0):

I handled this with wp_redirect in a very easy way:

I have already responded to ur needs here:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/417549/143910