# Change slug shortlink “/?p=” base in WordPress

Tags: functions, shortlink

How to Change The Default slug shortlink “/?p=” base in WordPress?

```
https://site.ltd/?p=115756
to

https://site.ltd/post/115756/
or
https://site.ltd/115756
```

Please provide the function code

Comment: You don't need code to do this, it can be done in the admin permalinks settings page

Answer (score 2):

Go to Settings->Permalinks and set a custom structure as:

`/post/%post_id%` or just `/%post_id%`

Answer (score -1):

I have written a snippet myself that I think it's what u need.

You need to active and replace for example `x.com/?p=100` with `x.com/100`

so this would help u:

```
add_action('wp', function() {
    $term = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
    
    if ( is_numeric( $term ) )
        wp_redirect(get_permalink($term));
});
```

Regards

Comment: This code will process /100 but it won't help the site generate that I don't think.

Comment: I use this on my big website. The problem has been begun when we send the query string URL in sms and some of our clients received it as un-linked. the problem was the question mark. so we had to implement a URL without a question mark. this is work and all are ok with that.